# Redis store geo infomation,

Tags: ruby, database, node.js, memcached, redis

I just meet a problem. I use redis to store the geo information. for
example:

```
hset 10001 la 41.000333
hset 10001 lo 121.999999
```

or

```
zadd la 41.xxxxx pk-value
zadd lo 121.xxxxx pk-value
```

about 40000 key-values
the key is for the terminal id, and value is set, storing the termianl
gps info.
I have a requirement to computing the around terminal.
for example, my location is 41.000123, 121.999988, and I want to the
fastest compute the terminal around my location, I have idea how to
compute the two location's distance. 
All I want is to think a way to fast iterate all data. In Redis 2.6 there is lua support. Can it help to resolve my problem?

Comment: You should ~never use `KEYS` in production. From [the docs](http://redis.io/commands/keys): "Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to find all values close to some coordinates? One way would be to use Lua scripting, another would be to store one sorted set for each approximate latitude/longitude (if you know in advance which granularity you require). Example:

```
zadd la.41 41.000333 pk-value
zadd lo.121 121.999999 pk-value
```

Then, when you need to find something close to some coords (let's say `(42.01, 122.03)`), you would do something like:

```
lat = 42.01
lon = 122.03
lat_min, lat_mid, lat_max = round(lat - 1), round(lat), round(lat + 1)
lon_min, lon_mid, lon_max = round(lon - 1), round(lon), round(lon + 1)
```

Thus, you would look in the sorted sets `la.41`, `la.42`, `la.43`, `lo.121`, `lo.122`, `lo.123`:

```
zinterstore close.${lat},${lon} 6 la.${lat_min}, la.${lat_mid}, la.${lat_max}, lo.${lon_min}, lo.${lon_mid}, lo.${lon_max}
```

Now, `close.${lat},${lon}` should contain the id of every terminal close to the supplied coordinates.

Obviously, you could store each coordinate with greater granularity, like `la.41.0`, `lo.121.0` and look only for terminals that close. Optionally, you could further filter the result in your client code.

Comment: Thank you for you ansower.but i can not around it .

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.
my data is like this:
---------------------------------------------
| id | la      | lo       | name | others   |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | 39.1111 | 116.1111 | xxx  | 
----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 39.2211 | 116.2233 | yyy  |


or i use the soered set to stroe the geo
zadd la.39.00 39.0000 1
zadd la.39.00 39.0001 2
zadd la.39.00 39.0003 3
...
zadd la.39.01 39.0100 4
...
zadd lo.116.00 116.0000 1
zadd lo.116.00 116.0001 2
...

zinterstore a 6 la.39.00 la.39.01 la.39.02 lo.116.00 lo.116.01 lo.116.02

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use geohashes, then you will be able to store (and search by) lon/lat with any precision you want, also it's relatively easy to get points which are in given bounding box.

For implementation with redis, have a look at [geodis](https://github.com/doat/geodis).